# Differences between ParametricPlot3D and NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I have a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ defined in a rather nasty way in mathematica however it's a smooth function and what not.  I am interested in $f'[t]$ and when I run it through ParametricPlot3D, it shows me what I expect it to look like.

When I try run $f'[t]$ or $f[t]$ through NIntegrate however, I always get a NIntegrate::inumr error saying the integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values.

What could be the cause of this, why is it that something I can ParametricPlot3D and also manually set up a numerical integration function for isn't working for NIntegrate?

Thanks in advance.

**Additional information:**

```
FF[t_] = Sqrt[d2 E^(- 0.2 t) +  d1 E^(0.2 t) - (b5 / (2 * 0.01))]
GG[s_] := -NIntegrate[Sqrt[d2 E^(- 0.2 t) +  d1 E^(0.2 t) - (b5 / (2 * 0.01))], {t, 0, s}]

Asym[t_?NumericQ] :=  FF[t] * {1, 0, 0} - (Sqrt[0.01 b5 + c5])/(FF[t]^2 )
{0, Cos[GG[t] + Arg[beta5] + Pi], Sin[GG[t] + Arg[beta5] + Pi]}
```

Everything else is just a real number (beta5 a complex number but Arg[beta5] is a number)

Both of these work fine (I see a nice smooth curve each time):

```
ParametricPlot3D[Asym[t], {t, 0, 1}]
ParametricPlot3D[Asym'[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

Neither of these work:

```
NIntegrate[Norm[Asym'[t]], {t, 0, 1}]
NIntegrate[Norm[Asym[t]], {t, 0, 1}]
```

If I calculate the following, it shows me a value for the first entry but not the second two entries implying it is the GG[t] stuffing things up seeing as GG[t] is not used in the first entry of Asym[t] at all.

```
NIntegrate[Asym[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: I guarantee you that I cannot answer this question, without more information - although, I might be able to guess that you need to restrict your function to be defined for only numerical values using something like `t_?NumericQ`.

Comment: Thanks, I have included additional details as requested.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Yes but I have now realised now it doesn't work for $f[t]$ either so I suppose the error is somewhere else.

Comment: I'm very sorry everyone but I have just found if I change the variable t to some other name in the integration, the integration works.  I don't understand why but it's now working.  Why is it using the same symbol t across different functions?

I guess I don't yet fully understand what := does, I just use it when I don't want the function to evaluate.  I apologise for wasting everyone's time on what turned out to be a basic mathematica misunderstanding.

Comment: No worries, it happens to us all. I've closed the question as too localised but up voted it too. It was a well specified question and you had done your homework. Welcome to Mathematica.SE and I hope we can be of help in future.

Comment: Scoping issue wherein a `t` in NIntegrate gets captured. Can repair either by also having `GG[s_?NumericQ] := ...` or else by defining it with its own `t`, via GG[s_] := 
 Module[{t}, -NIntegrate[
    Sqrt[d2 E^(-0.2 t) + d1 E^(0.2 t) - (b5/(2*0.01))], {t, 0, s}]]. I will add that such questions are more easily answered if all code is provided, in this case that would include assignments for `d2`, `b5`, etc.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau if you would prefer to post that as an answer, I can reopen it if you want.

Comment: @Verbeia Yes, that scoping seems like the sort of thing that might be of general use, hence suitable for an MSE response.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I've reopened it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you have is a scoping issue. The `t` dummy variable in the NIntegrate may be getting captured by symbolic preprocessing of NIntegrate. I'm not certain because I do not see quite the behavior you do. Specifically, this seems to work fine.

```
NIntegrate[Norm[Asym[t]], {t, 0, 1}]
```